# Why d3-sankey transition not working correct?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  props: {
    width: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1500
    },
    height: {
      type: Number,
      default: 300
    },

    duration: {
      type: Number,
      default: 250
    },
    tooltipDuration: {
      type: Number,
      default: 200
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.setSvg();
    this.setTooltip();

    this.drawSankey();
  },

  data: () => ({
    data: {
      nodes: [
        { name: 'Новый' },
        { name: 'Принят' },
        { name: 'Подтвержден' },
        { name: 'Отменен' }
      ],
      links: [
        {
          source: 'Новый',
          target: 'Подтвержден',
          value: 70
        },
        {
          source: 'Новый',
          target: 'Отменен',
          value: 30
        },
        {
          source: 'Новый',
          target: 'Принят',
          value: 15
        },
        {
          source: 'Подтвержден',
          target: 'Отменен',
          value: 15
        },
        {
          source: 'Принят',
          target: 'Отменен',
          value: 10
        },
        {
          source: 'Принят',
          target: 'Подтвержден',
          value: 5
        }
      ]
    },

    sankeySvg: null,

    nodes: null,
    links: null,
    labels: null,
    tooltip: null
  }),

  computed: {
    colorPalette() {
      return d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
    },

    sankey() {
      return d3
        .sankey()
        .nodeId(d => d.name)
        .nodeAlign(d3.sankey().sankeyJustify)
        .nodeWidth(15)
        .nodePadding(10)
        .nodeSort((a, b) => d3.descending(a.value, b.value))
        .linkSort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.value, b.value))
        .iterations(32)
        .size([this.width, this.height]);
    },

    sankeyData() {
      const { nodes, links } = this.data;

      return this.sankey({
        nodes: nodes.map(d => Object.assign({}, d)),
        links: links
          .map(d => Object.assign({}, d))
      });
    },

    sankeyLinkHorizontal() {
      return d3.sankey().sankeyLinkHorizontal();
    }
  },

  methods: {
    setSvg() {
      this.sankeySvg = d3
        .select(this.$el)
        .append('svg')
        .attr('viewBox', [0, 0, this.width, this.height])
        .style('width', '100%')
        .style('height', 'auto');
    },

    setTooltip() {
      this.tooltip = d3
        .select(this.$el)
        .select('.main-tooltip')
        .style('display', 'none');
    },

    drawSankey() {
      this.drawLinks();
      this.drawNodes();
      this.drawLabels();
    },

    redrawSankey() {
      this.data = {
        nodes: [
          { name: 'Новый' },
          { name: 'Принят' },
          { name: 'Подтвержден' },
          { name: 'Отменен' }
        ],
        links: [
          {
            source: 'Новый',
            target: 'Подтвержден',
            value: 30
          },
          {
            source: 'Новый',
            target: 'Отменен',
            value: 10
          },
          {
            source: 'Новый',
            target: 'Принят',
            value: 25
          },
          {
            source: 'Подтвержден',
            target: 'Отменен',
            value: 45
          },
          {
            source: 'Принят',
            target: 'Отменен',
            value: 10
          },
          {
            source: 'Принят',
            target: 'Подтвержден',
            value: 15
          }
        ]
      };

      this.redrawLinks();
      this.redrawNodes();
      this.redrawLabels();
    },

    drawNodes() {
      const { nodes } = this.sankeyData;

      this.nodes = this.sankeySvg
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'nodes')
        .selectAll('rect')
        .data(nodes)
        .join('rect')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .attr('x', d => d.x0)
        .attr('y', d => d.y0)
        .attr('height', d => d.y1 - d.y0)
        .attr('width', d => d.x1 - d.x0)
        .attr('fill', d => this.colorPalette(d.name))
        .on('mouseover', this.onNodeMouseOver)
        .on('mouseout', this.onNodeMouseOut);
    },

    redrawNodes() {
      const { nodes } = this.sankeyData;

      this.nodes
        .data(nodes)
        .attr('fill', d => this.colorPalette(d.name))
        .attr('x', d => d.x0)
        .attr('y', d => d.y0)
        .attr('height', d => d.y1 - d.y0);
    },

    drawLabels() {
      const { nodes } = this.sankeyData;

      this.labels = this.sankeySvg
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'labels')
        .selectAll('text')
        .data(nodes)
        .join('text')
        .attr('class', 'label')
        .attr('x', d => (d.x0 < this.width / 2 ? d.x1 + 8 : d.x0 - 8))
        .attr('y', d => (d.y1 + d.y0) / 2)
        .attr('text-anchor', d => (d.x0 < this.width / 2 ? 'start' : 'end'))
        .attr('dy', '0.35em')
        .text(d => d.name);
    },

    redrawLabels() {
      const { nodes } = this.sankeyData;

      this.labels
        .data(nodes)
        .attr('x', d => (d.x0 < this.width / 2 ? d.x1 + 8 : d.x0 - 8))
        .attr('y', d => (d.y1 + d.y0) / 2)
        .attr('text-anchor', d => (d.x0 < this.width / 2 ? 'start' : 'end'));
    },

    drawLinks() {
      const { links } = this.sankeyData;

      this.links = this.sankeySvg
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'links')
        .attr('fill', 'transparent')
        .selectAll('path')
        .data(links)
        .join('path')
        .attr('class', 'link')
        .attr('d', this.sankeyLinkHorizontal)
        .attr('stroke', d => this.colorPalette(d.source.name))
        .attr('stroke-width', d => d.width)
        .attr('opacity', 0.67)
        .on('mouseover', this.onLinkMouseOver)
        .on('mousemove', this.onMouseMove)
        .on('mouseout', this.onLinkMouseOut);
    },

    redrawLinks() {
      const { links } = this.sankeyData;

      this.links
        .data(links)
        .attr('stroke', d => this.colorPalette(d.source.name))
        .attr('d', this.sankeyLinkHorizontal)
        .attr('stroke-width', d => d.width);
    },

    onMouseOver(selected) {
      const linksNodes = [];

      this.links
        .filter(d => {
          if (
            !selected.source &&
            (d.source.index === selected.index ||
              d.target.index === selected.index)
          )
            linksNodes.push(d.source.index, d.target.index);

          return selected.source
            ? d.index !== selected.index
            : d.source.name !== selected.name &&
                d.target.name !== selected.name;
        })
        .transition()
        .duration(this.duration)
        .attr('opacity', 0.3);

      this.nodes
        .filter(d =>
          selected.source
            ? !d.sourceLinks.includes(selected) &&
              !d.targetLinks.includes(selected)
            : d.name !== selected.name && !linksNodes.includes(d.index)
        )
        .transition()
        .duration(this.duration)
        .style('opacity', 0.3);
    },

    onMouseMove() {
      const { innerWidth: windowWidth } = window;

      const {
        clientWidth: tooltipWidth,
        clientHeight: tooltipHeight
      } = this.$refs.tooltip;

      const { pageX, layerX, layerY } = currentEvent;

      const left =
        pageX + tooltipWidth * 1.2 > windowWidth
          ? layerX - tooltipWidth
          : layerX + 4;

      const top = layerY - tooltipHeight;

      this.tooltip.style('left', left + 'px').style('top', top + 'px');
    },

    onMouseOut() {
      this.links
        .transition()
        .duration(this.duration)
        .attr('opacity', 0.67);

      this.nodes
        .transition()
        .duration(this.duration)
        .style('opacity', 1);
    },

    onNodeMouseOver(selected) {
      this.tooltip
        .style('display', 'block')
        .transition()
        .duration(this.tooltipDuration)
        .style('opacity', 1);

      this.tooltip.select('div').text(`${selected.name} (${selected.value})`);

      this.onMouseMove();

      this.onMouseOver(selected);
    },

    onNodeMouseOut() {
      this.tooltip
        .transition()
        .duration(this.tooltipDuration * 0.2)
        .style('opacity', 0);

      this.onMouseOut();
    },

    onLinkMouseOver(selected) {
      this.tooltip
        .style('display', 'block')
        .transition()
        .duration(this.tooltipDuration)
        .style('opacity', 1);

      this.tooltip.select('div').text(`
          ${selected.source.name} -> ${selected.target.name} (${selected.value})`);

      this.onMouseOver(selected);
    },

    onLinkMouseOut() {
      this.tooltip
        .transition()
        .duration(this.tooltipDuration * 0.2)
        .style('opacity', 0);

      this.onMouseOut();
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#sankey {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
 #sankey .main-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
}
 #sankey .label {
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-array@1"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-collection@1"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-path@1"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-shape@1"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-sankey@0"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<div id="sankey" @click="redrawSankey">
    <div class="main-tooltip main-tooltip--absolute main-tooltip--no-events main-tooltip--rounded" ref="tooltip">
        <div class="main-tooltip__content main-tooltip__content--small main-tooltip__content--nowrap"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have a sankey diagram. There was a task to smoothly process the change in the chart data, after several hours of testing, I completely despaired.

In general, the problem is that after I try to add smooth animation to the d3 elements of signatures, nodes and links

Code of drawing

```
nodes = sankeySvg
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'nodes')
        .selectAll('rect')
        .data(nodes)
        .join('rect')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .attr('x', d => d.x0)
        .attr('y', d => d.y0)
        .attr('height', d => d.y1 - d.y0)
        .attr('width', d => d.x1 - d.x0)
        .attr('fill', d => colorPalette(d.name))
        .on('mouseover', onNodeMouseOver)
        .on('mouseout', onNodeMouseOut);

labels = sankeySvg
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'labels')
        .selectAll('text')
        .data(nodes)
        .join('text')
        .attr('class', 'label')
        .attr('x', d => (d.x0 < width / 2 ? d.x1 + 8 : d.x0 - 8))
        .attr('y', d => (d.y1 + d.y0) / 2)
        .attr('text-anchor', d => (d.x0 < width / 2 ? 'start' : 'end'))
        .attr('dy', '0.35em')
        .text(d => d.name);

links = this.sankeySvg
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'links')
        .attr('fill', 'transparent')
        .selectAll('path')
        .data(links)
        .join('path')
        .attr('class', 'link')
        .attr('d', d3.sankeyLinkHorizontal())
        .attr('stroke', d => colorPalette(d.source.name))
        .attr('stroke-width', d => d.width)
        .attr('opacity', 0.67)
        .on('mouseover', onLinkMouseOver)
        .on('mousemove', onMouseMove)
        .on('mouseout', onLinkMouseOut);
```

Code of redrawing

```
nodes
        .data(nodes)
        .attr('fill', d => colorPalette(d.name))
        .transtion() // If delete
        .duration(200) // it works
        .attr('x', d => d.x0)
        .attr('y', d => d.y0)
        .attr('height', d => d.y1 - d.y0);

labels
        .data(nodes)
        .transtion() // If delete
        .duration(200) // it works
        .attr('x', d => (d.x0 < width / 2 ? d.x1 + 8 : d.x0 - 8))
        .attr('y', d => (d.y1 + d.y0) / 2)
        .attr('text-anchor', d => (d.x0 < width / 2 ? 'start' : 'end'));

links
        .data(linksData)
        .attr('stroke', d => colorPalette(d.source.name))
        .transtion() // If delete
        .duration(200) // it works
        .attr('d', d3.sankeyLinkHorizontal())
        .attr('stroke-width', d => d.width);
```

Everything starts to go awry, as a result of this

[Source diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdNEP.png)

it turns out

[Incorrect result (now)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1X16.png)

instead of this

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHMiZ.png)

I would really appreciate any help. -_-

Comment: can you share code snippet with data, would really help addressing your issue.

Comment: @mamounothman added